# FragmentTransaction add() behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

Working with fragments I've always used `replace()` for my transactions, but I wish I didn't have to save instance states anymore to restore a fragment's view and prevent reloading when coming back to that fragment. So, I've decided to work with `add()`. The thing is when I add another fragment, the previous fragment view remains in the background and that's fine (that's the behavior I expected), but the problem is I can actually interact with the views in the background. **Example:**

**Fragment A** has a `Button`

**Fragment B** has a `TextView`

When I add **Fragment A** and later add **Fragment B**, I'm able to click on **Fragment A's** `Button`, even staying on **Fragment B's** view.

I'm using:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            add(getRootViewContainer(),fragment,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

if (shouldGoBack) 
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

where `getRootViewContainer()` returns the **id** of the `FrameLayout` I'm using as my activity main container.

Now, is it really the default behavior of `add()`?

If so, is there a proper way to avoid this or one just has to use `replace()`?

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? Try some below if you haven't. I'm sure mine will work, because I use it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentBehind); //works for me!
```

example :

```
//I have it globally available
FragmentTransaction trans = MainActivity.getManager().beginTransaction(); 

//not globally 
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MapFragment newFragment = new newFragment();
trans.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, tag);
trans.hide(this);
trans.addToBackStack(tag);
trans.commit();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry the delay. I was using this approach of hiding and showing fragments, but I wanted to avoid this thing of when I must show one or hide the other. Do you know any other ways we could do it? Thanks.

Comment: Disable focus of the layout behind? I really don't know any other clean way. This method works best with me, and I'm using about 15 different kind of Fragments. If I want to I can have 100+ fragments, but everything goes well because of the function above.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do here is  just hide previous fragment  at the time of transaction of current fragment.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  Fragment newFragment= new MyFragment ();
  ft.hide(CurrentFragment.this);
  ft.show(newFragment);
  ft.commit();
```

It worked for me just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a default behaviour of add().
If you really don't want to user replace(), you can try to disable views which are inside "old" fragment.